# Substitute entries in a large numpy tensor with dictionary values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge numpy tensor and I have a huge dictionary, what is the fastest way of substituting the entries in the tensor(assuming they are the keys) with those with the corresponding values in dictionary.

For e.g. I have a tensor of million entries like :

```
np.asarray([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[2,4,5,]],
             [[2,3,4],[7,8,9],[10,11,23],[6,3,1]],
             [[4,55,6],[90,8,2],[1,2,3],[0,94,1]],
             [[6,7,8],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,8,2]],
             [[9,8,8],[4,5,6],[34,55,6],[3,52,2]]
             ...................................
             ...................................]

dictionary = {4:6,5:67,8:99,.........} #million entries in dictionary
```

Comment: whats your array dim? and actually what to want to do with dictionary and array ?

Comment: array is 3D tensor and I want to substitute its entries with dictionary entries

Comment: do you want that 4th entry of array be kay and 6th be value? for ex in first element of dict ???

Comment: Yes I want to replace 4 in the array with 6 as per dictionary

Comment: so i add an answer as point to your solution !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the fastest way to do this, but here you go:

```
In [33]: arr = np.asarray([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[2,4,5,]],
    ...:              [[2,3,4],[7,8,9],[10,11,23],[6,3,1]],
    ...:              [[4,55,6],[90,8,2],[1,2,3],[0,94,1]],
    ...:              [[6,7,8],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,8,2]],
    ...:              [[9,8,8],[4,5,6],[34,55,6],[3,52,2]]])

In [34]: dct = {int(random.random()*100): int(random.random()*100) for _ in xrange(100)}

In [35]: arr.ravel()[:] = np.fromiter((dct.get(x, x) for x in arr.ravel()), dtype=arr.dtype)

In [36]: arr
Out[36]: 
array([[[18, 94, 53],
        [71, 73,  6],
        [35,  7,  9],
        [94, 71, 73]],

       [[94, 53, 71],
        [35,  7,  9],
        [10, 42, 15],
        [ 6, 53, 18]],

       [[71, 50,  6],
        [90,  7, 94],
        [18, 94, 53],
        [ 0, 94, 18]],

       [[ 6, 35,  7],
        [53, 71, 73],
        [ 6, 35,  7],
        [ 9,  7, 94]],

       [[ 9,  7,  7],
        [71, 73,  6],
        [99, 50,  6],
        [53, 52, 94]]])
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit, whats going on in here?

Comment: @Lanc [`ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) returns a flattened view of the array, so, in the code I am updating that view's items with the list on the RHS. I think a better option would be [`np.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) which is gaunranteed to return a view not copy of the actual array: `arr.flat[:] = [dct.get(x, x) for x in arr.flat]`

Comment: @Lanc I've updated my code to use `numpy.fromiter` instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

If your dict has integer keys, you could simply convert it into a vector `v` where `v[i] = dictionary[i]`. Then, just index `v` with the big tensor.

```
# Assuming foo is the big tensor and d is the dictionary
# Set up v
v = np.arange(max(d.keys())+1)
for key,val in d.iteritems():
  v[key] = val

# Do the replacements all at once:
replaced = v[foo]
```

If you run into `IndexError` issues, try `v = np.arange(foo.max()+1)` instead.

Comment: dictionary has integer keys but values can be float as well

Answer (score 0):

```
np.asarray([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[2,4,5,]],
             [[2,3,4],[7,8,9],[10,11,23],[6,3,1]],
             [[4,55,6],[90,8,2],[1,2,3],[0,94,1]],
             [[6,7,8],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,8,2]],
             [[9,8,8],[4,5,6],[34,55,6],[3,52,2]]
             ...................................
             ...................................]

dictionary = {4:6,5:67,8:99,.........}

#you must do something like this

for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
 dictionary[array[k]]=array[v]
```

Comment: What if dictionary has more entries then the tensor itself?

Comment: so you can compare the `len` of them ! i will add it in edit !